# JQUERY / PLUGIN call function from outside / arguments

Tags: jquery, function, plugins, arguments

i am trying to have a simple function in this plugin by David Bushell.

[link to index](http://atelier37.at/stackoverflow/index.html)

[link to javascript-file](http://atelier37.at/stackoverflow/jquery.nestable.js)

name of function : edit_mainlink

```
 edit_mainlink: function(argument)
    {
        var my_var = argument;

        console.log(my_var);    
    },
```

how can i call the function from outside and pass arguments? thanks for helping. till.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

`$('#nestable').data('nestable').__proto__.edit_mainlink('something')`

Which will simply log `'something'` to the console